# Does $ \Delta p \Delta x = \Delta E\Delta t$?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Two formulations of the Uncertainty Principle are
$$ \Delta p \Delta x \geq \hbar/2$$
and
$$ \Delta E \Delta t\geq \hbar/2$$

Does  $ \Delta p \Delta x = \Delta E\Delta t$? I know the Uncertainty Principle is an inequality and not an identity. But I think it is possible that they are equal or only differ by a constant. I think it leads to the differential equation $\partial p/\partial t = \partial E/\partial x$. In words, the time derivative of momentum equals the space derivative of energy.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53808/discussion-on-question-by-hooch-does-delta-p-delta-x-delta-e-delta-t).

Answer (score 4):

The time-energy uncertainty relation is complicated; there are lots of caveats that go along with it, and the simple form you give is fairly hand-wavy.  The "actual" uncertainty relation is
\begin{equation}
  \Delta E \frac{\Delta A}{\left| \frac{d \langle A \rangle}{dt} \right|} \geq \frac{\hbar}{2},
\end{equation}
for some other operator $A$.  [Here](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/uncertainty.html) is a nice and reasonably elementary discussion of the problems with it.  So the basic answer is that $\Delta E \Delta t$ is not really precise or meaningful enough to equal something that is precisely meaningful like $\Delta p \Delta x$.

But it's reasonable to have this feeling that there's some connection.  For example, in *classical* mechanics, if you're talking about a particle of mass $m$, you have $p = m\, \frac{dx}{dt}$ and $E = \frac{1}{2}m \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2$.  [You can calculate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2064222/26404) that
\begin{equation}
 \Delta E = \frac{1}{2} m\, \Delta \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 = m\, \left|\frac{dx}{dt}\right|\, \Delta \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) = \left|\frac{dx}{dt}\right|\, \Delta p.
\end{equation}
We could plug this into the right-hand side above, wave our hands and ignore some important facts, to find
\begin{equation}
 \Delta E \frac{\Delta x}{\left| \frac{d \langle x \rangle}{dt} \right|} = \Delta p \Delta x \frac{\left| \frac{d x}{dt} \right|}{\left| \frac{d \langle x \rangle}{dt} \right|}
\end{equation}
However, I cannot stress enough that this is only a hand-wavy correspondence.  I skipped over so many important details here that I'm almost ashamed to have written it, and I certainly am not claiming that this works out for quantum mechanics in any way we should care about.

Again, to answer your question: no, $\Delta E \Delta t = \Delta p \Delta x$ is not something we can generally expect.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53809/discussion-on-answer-by-mike-does-delta-p-delta-x-delta-e-delta-t).

Answer (score 3):

$\Delta$ means uncertainty and not the difference.

Dimensionally it is correct but can you??? calculate the position of electrons from the nucleus with the equation.

In Quantum Mechanics the things work very different from what we think, So think logically.

Comment: Look at it this way. Lets ASSUME that it does mean difference and we can take limits. If we do that we are left with an equation that, with the exception of the minus sign, confirms one of Hamiltons equations.

Comment: But he is converting it into F=ma.

Comment: Each term in the differential equation does turn out to be equal to Newtons second law, F=ma. When we take the limits of the variances and turn it into a differential equation it becomes a classical formula.

Comment: Delta means variance. If a measured value is equal to its expected value, variance is zero. When we take the limit as the variance approaches zero, we are converting the equation into a classical equation. You should not be surprised that doing that yields a Classical result, ie F=ma.

Comment: I could ask you "what does uncertainty mean"? Does it mean standard deviation of many individual observations? And if that is what it means then the Uncertainty Principle would not preclude the existence of a set of observations of momentum and position that were exactly correct. Why? Because, if that were the case, it would be the standard deviations of the data sets that obeys the Uncertainty Principle and not any individual set of observations. Maybe that is the case? If so I am listening.

Comment: I would like to point out that there is an alternative differential equation implied by the equality stated in the original question. The alternative differential equation is dx/dt = dE/dp, where p is momentum and E is total energy, dx/dt is, of course velocity. That is **precisely** Hamilton's equation for velocity ( dq/dt = dH/dp).

Comment: Dear reader, this is not a new and unpublished theory. It is simply an observation that I think is correct. It is a perfect question for this site. The problem is that some of the members here spoke to soon and now they are stuck and they have to find a way out.